# SYSCLK frequency setting route for STM32F103C8

Tags: stm32, microcontroller, clock

Need to display SYSCLK frequency setting route for STM32F103C8. There are initial data:
SYSCLK = 64MHz; HSE generator; AHB Pre = 8 ; MCO - HSI.

I got the following route -> [image with route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9cto.png)

But it turned out to be incorrect, since the configured frequency should be 9Mhz. But I don't understand why not 8Mhz.
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Which frequency is supposed to be 9MHz? And MCO is 8MHz as HSI is 8MHz.

Comment: @Codo HCLK is 9MHz

Answer (score 0):

You have indicated that you selected HSI as the MCO.  HSI has a fixed frequency of 8MHz, so you should expect 8MHz on the pin.

The only way you can make 9MHz is to use the PLL to multiply the 8MHz crystal by 9 to get 72MHz, and then set one of the bus dividers to 8.  This will give you 9MHz on the AHB or APB.

The diagram appears to show that the SYSCLK output from the MCO is taken before AHB divider, so even if you have a 9MHz AHB, you cannot get 9MHz on the MCO.